# Hijri calendar with jquery 1.10

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, hijri

I have used Hijri calendar - Keith wood calendar , but this use jquery 1.9 and I want similar calendar with jquery 1.10 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed other jquery plugins and make only keith-wood plugins that calendar need then works fine.
there was a conflict with jquery plugins

Answer (score 1):

you can use this hijri calendar that support all jquery versions.

[amib Calendar](http://amib.ir/weblog/?page_id=316) and [hasheminezhad Calendar](http://hasheminezhad.com/datepicker)

Comment: This is not Hijri calendar , it Farsi calendar